# Troubleshooting WordPress Template Editing: Identical Content Across Pages

Tags: wordpress, templates

I need your help. I'm editing a template in WordPress, and I've come across the following issues. I've edited a new page and it looks just fine, then I edited a post and it also looks just fine. The problem occurs when I create a new page and every other page as well as a post, the content, although changed, remains the same on every page.  I'm editing the template without subscribing to the Pro version but that shouldn't be a problem? Does anyone know what the problem is and how I can solve this issue?
Thank you all.

I tried adding a completely new template in Gutenberg for my newly created page, but then that new template applies to all pages. Even the text on every page becomes identical, despite each being different.

Comment: "I'm editing the template" - templates are generally shared across multiple things, so I'm not clear on what you are editing.